# Detect area transparent of image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

i have a problem with this image

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3m2l.png

I would like to find out where the image is transparent. I use this image as a background, but the content should start from the transparent part not before and not after. I have this code

```
<div style="
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3m2l.png');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 98;
  margin-right: -1px;
"></div>
<div id="start-text">HELLO</div>
```

I would like to place that "HELLO" inside the transparent part in an automatic way (clearly the image will be scaled to the screen)

Comment: A *general* algorithm will not be able to prove for certain that there's a lovely rectangular hole in the middle because images can have transparency anywhere. For other answerers: would you be willing to package some metadata with your image? Say, four 2D cartesian coordinates?

Comment: If you have the original image and that is not going to change, why not do a calculation based on the aspect ratio then you can figure out where the transparent bit is depending on the size of your screen, as my firewall blocks the imgur I am unable to help

Comment: @Pete: exact, the image not change

Comment: This basically boils down to lots of tedious calculations: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ce71r3j8/

Comment: @ChrisG perfect!! But if i insert video width:100%; height:100%; not work.. i want occupied all white space... can calc space disponibility?